# "hinter/vor sich" — Dativ oder Akkusativ?

Tags: grammatical-case

Ich habe häufig den Ausdruck *hinter sich*/*vor sich* gesehen, wie z. B.:

> Er hat eine schwere Zeit hinter **sich**.

Ich bin mir nicht sicher ob das *sich* als Dativ verwendet wird. Sagt man:

> Ich habe eine schwere Zeit hinter **mir**.

Comment: Schönes Zitat von [Max Reger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Reger#Reception) als Reaktion auf eine negative Rezension: "Ich sitze in dem kleinsten Zimmer in meinem Hause. Ich habe Ihre Kritik vor mir. Im nächsten Augenblick wird sie hinter mir sein!"

Answer (score 4):

Dativ, wenn statisch.

> Ich habe eine schwere Zeit hinter mir.

Akkusativ, wenn dynamisch.

> Ich habe eine schwere Zeit hinter mich gebracht.

Siehe auch, [canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/2Kasus.html#Anchor-hinter-30974).

Answer (score 0):

> Sagt man, "ich habe eine schwere Zeit hinter mir"?

Yes, this is correct.

*hinter sich haben* can have the more literal meaning of having something/somebody behind the back (i.e. location, as in the Max Reger quote) or refer to an (unpleasant) activity or time that you overcame (temporal meaning). In either case it is used with Dativ. You can ask: "Wo ist die Zeit? Wo ist die Kritik?"

In active use, you could say:

> Ich habe eine schwere Zeit hinter mich gebracht.

which would be used with Akkusativ, because you'd ask "Wohin habe ich die Zeit gebracht?"